# Proof Attempt: Non-decreasing continuous CDF is standard uniformly distributed

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-verification, uniform-distribution

Proof Attempt:
For any random variable $X$ with non-decreasing continuous cdf $F(x)=\Pr(X≤x)$ (note that the inverse function does not necessarily exist due to flat regions in $F$), I wish to prove that the random variable $F(X)\sim U(0,1)$.

Note that because $F(x)$ is non-decreasing and is at least $0$ and at most $1$, $F(X)\le p \Longrightarrow X \le \max\{x:p=F(x)\}$ where $p∈[0,1]$.
Graphically, $(\max\{x:p=F(x)\},p)$ is simply the rightmost point of $F(x)$ at a specific magnitude $p$.

The cdf $G(p)$ of the random variable $F(X)$ is:

$$G(p)=\Pr(F(X)≤p)=\Pr(X≤\max\{x:p=F(x)\})=F(\max\{x:p=F(x)\})=p.$$

$G(p)=p:p∈[0,1]$ is the standard uniform cdf, so $F(X)\sim U(0,1)$.

Comment: It's a bit messy. How about cleaning it up. Here's an attempt. We want to prove that for an r.v. $X$ with continuous CDF $F$, the r.v. $F(X)$ is uniform on $(0,1)$. Let $p \in (0,1)$. Notice that because $F$ is nondecreasing, $F(X) \leq p$ is equivalent to $X \leq \sup \{ x : F(x) \leq p \}$. I claim that this event has probability $p$. <Proof of claim>. Therefore $F(X)$ is uniform on $(0,1)$.

Comment: What do do about the flat regions is the crux of the matter. $\qquad$

Comment: Your proof look ok to me right now.  I shall return later and see if I missed some nitpicking detail$\,\ldots\qquad$